# Youtube Lag after Chrome update to 61 version

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube

After I updated yesterday my Chrome to 61 version it became so much slower. I can't play youtube videos even in 240p without lag. I tried disabling hardware acceleration, resetting Chrome flags to defaults and disabling extensions.
Also, I changed my swappiness from 60 to 10. And improved cache management.

```
# Decrease swap usage to a more reasonable level
vm.swappiness=10
# Improve cache management
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
```

I also deleted contents of my `.cache` folder and did a reboot. 
After all these improvements my computer is running much faster but Chrome is still terrible.

What could it be? I only found one complaint in Google production forum and no solution.
Exact version I am currently using: `Version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: According to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/I9iTaJTtlnM;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/category$3Awindows-10) and [that](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?visit_id=0-636128440356464766-3095278717&rd=1#!topic/chrome/DJ8pdgTwCXw;context-place=forum/chrome) messages, there's a geral complain about this Chrome version. They took about alternatives. Good idea to consider them.

Comment: So the only solution I have is to switch to Firefox...

Comment: No, Firefox is not the only solution. You can try downgrade Chrome to formerly version, or try Chromium. Even Opera runs in Ubuntu, but it's not so different from Chrome.

Comment: Correction: "only acceptable solution"

Comment: You should try Brave :)

Comment: Brave is based on Chromium and I tried it the same bug exists but can't disable it cuz there are no flags :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting this to Disabled solved this problem for me:

`chrome://flags/#enable-color-correct-rendering`

Comment: Great! So simple (after somebody talks, of course)...

Comment: I think my Chrome was never this fast. Is this a new feature that wasn't there before? or it just wasn't enabled by default in previous versions? I would like some background on this. Thanks.

Comment: People are experiencing wrong colors after updates to 61, so my guess is this flag was there before (I have it in Chrome 60, but Default setting meant "Disabled"; in 61 they apparently made it Enabled by default. This is all I was able to gather from Google.

Comment: It's strange they enabled an unstable feature. Maybe they enabled it by accident.

Comment: This fixed a painful lag on Google Maps for me too