# Contrast blacks on Youtube Chrome 61, Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, colors

I've been noticed recently on YouTube through Chrome that deep blacks aren't displaying properly. Downloading the video or watching it Firefox shows the appropriate blacks. Any suggestions as what would be causing the artifacting?

[see example of weird contrast blacks on youtube hosts's t-shirt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EasFk.png)

Comment: I saw days a go a problem involving youtube rendering about Chrome 61. Look if [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956125/youtube-lag-after-chrome-update-to-61-version) solves your problem. It may help you

Comment: Not at all! Don't forget to upvote Piaskal answer...

Comment: Done! I also copied the answer here and linked to Paskal's answer in case someone finds this but not the other by not seeing your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my solution in an answer by user Piaskal:

> > > Setting this to Disabled solved this problem for me:
> > >
> > > chrome://flags/#enable-color-correct-rendering

From [this question about a laggy YouTube after Chrome 61 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956125/youtube-lag-after-chrome-update-to-61-version)

Comment: Cheers! Good answer!